# How to index a binary column in MySQL, or should I split into two tables?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm trying to index a binary column.  It can be either 1 (which it is for 3million rows), or 0 (which it typically is for ~100 rows).

Using MySQL's explain it appears to be completely ignoring the index I've created, even if I use `USE INDEX` in my query.

Is it just simply not possible to index a column like this?  Does that mean any query dependent on it will require a full table scan?

I can see one solution would be to split the data into two tables, and it would kind of make sense based on the business requirements.

Any other options?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with binary exactly? What's the datatype?

Comment: Please post table structure, index definition and explain plan.

Comment: "tinyint".  By binary I simply meant that the column only ever contains one of two values.  I.e. very low cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

When the value is 1 (the common value), it is a lot ignore the index and simply scan the table, tossing the few rows that don't apply.

When the value is 0 (the very rare value), the index will be used, and be very effective.  However, this *may* apply only when you explicitly say `WHERE col = 0`.

Without seeing the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT`, it is hard to guess what other optimizations might be useful.  One that comes to mind:  a composite index *starting* with that column.

It is also hard to judge whether splitting into two tables would help.  Would you sometimes need to `UNION` them back together?  If splitting cleans up the code, then good.  Note that some other columns may go away in one table or the other.

Partitioning rarely helps.